# Different Layouts in IE8 on Different Web Servers

Tags: css, iis, encoding, permissions, internet-explorer-8

Last night, I experienced a strange behavior in IE8 as I saw two noticeably different layouts of a page that's being hosted on separate servers.  On my local web server, the header markup looked as expected with its left aligned logo and right aligned and stacked utility links, all of which displayed on a centered page.  On a staging web server and a production web server, the header markup was completely invisible on the page, as it was positioned 152px higher than the page.

I understand that the ".header .hog" selector CSS code below is a hack.  It was a quick fix for changes that needed to get deployed immediately.  Rather than analyzing how to improve this code, I'm more interested in knowing the cause(s) of these presentation differences in IE8.  A few question that I have are:

- Could the markup have different encoding?  If so, what is the best way in determining this possibility?  And, which setting, if any, in IIS7 is responsible for encoding output?
- Could permissions be the cause of this problem?
- Is there a feature in IIS7 that determines whether or not the markup is strictly interpreted?
- Is there a difference between the Layout Engines of IE8 on Vista and IE8 on XP?

My markup code is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
            <h1 id="logo"><img src="/img/logo.jpg" /></h1>
            <div class="hog">
                <a class="see">Text</a>
                <div class="more">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="utility-links">
                <a>link1</a>|
                <a>link2</a>|
                <a>link3</a>|
                <a>link4</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS code is as follows:

```
* {
    border:none;
    line-height:normal;
    margin:0;
    outline:none;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

body{
    background:#70133F;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
    font-size:0;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.content{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:970px;
}

.header{
    height:160px;
}

.header #logo{
    float:left;
    font-size:0;
    height:124px;
    margin:25px 0 0 18px;
    width:204px;
}

.header .util-links {
    color:#E83F00;
    font:bold 12px;
    float:right;
    margin:135px 15px 0 0;
    text-align:right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.header .util-links a {
    padding:0 10px;
}

.header .hog {
    height:3px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-152px;
    text-align:right;
    width:945px;
}

.header .hog a.see-holiday {
    color:#E83F00;
    font:bold 12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    height:40px;
    width:254px;
}

.header .hog .guidelines {
    display:none;
    margin-left:524px;
    text-align:left;
    width:428px;
}
```

Thanks for the help.  Happy Thanksgiving, everyone!
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference between the
>   Layout Engines of IE8 on Vista and IE8
>   on XP?

If I understood it right, it appears that you are not only having 2 servers but you are also accessing the site from 2 different computers, one running XP and another Vista. Open the IE developer tools in both computers and observe the browser mode and document mode. Perhaps one of the browsers has been set permanently to IE7 compatibility mode? Or one of the servers is sending the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` tag forcing a compatible mode?

There is a slight difference between IE on XP and Vista because IE uses OS controls to render certain controls such as buttons, textboxes, select boxes and scrollbars. However, the difference in layout caused by that should not be that drastic.

For finding differences in headers, you can install a tool such as fiddler or httpwatch and inspect them in both machines.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and good ideas.

The issue is more related to the page being hosted on different web servers than the page being displayed on different operating systems.

Neither server is adding the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> tag to the web page or the "X-UA-Compatible:IE=EmulateIE7" tag to the HTTP header.  Also, the browsers are not set permanently in IE7 compatibility mode. 

Instead of emulating IE7 markup in IE8, I want to fix this presentation difference at the root cause.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: What does the Dev Tools show for the Document Mode and the Browser Mode?  

Is one of the pages using a URL without dots in the Hostname (Intranet Zone)?  Those are put in CompatMode by default.

Comment: I just learned that IE sets all publicly accessible Internet sites to run in IE 8 browser mode and all Intranet sites to IE 8 compatibility browser mode, which gracefully shows content designed for older web browsers well in IE8.  This alone explains why the locally served page looks correct and the browser mode is set to IE8 compatibility mode.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks, @phreeskier, this comment led me directly to the issue i was seeing.